# Is it possible to create frozen sets with curly braces?

Tags: python, frozenset

It appears that one can only create a `frozenset` using the `frozenset()` constructor.

Is this true or is there a textual way to create a frozen set?  I can find no evidence one way or the other [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#frozenset).

Comment: There's no literal for a `frozenset`, yes.

Comment: Which is a shame, because I don't think there's any particular reason the grammar couldn't be extended to allow prefixing similar to what string literals support. `f{1, 2, 3}` could be a `frozenset` literal. It wouldn't conflict with any existing syntax.

Comment: I guess frozensets just aren't used commonly enough for a literal syntax to be needed (of course that's a chicken and egg situation). As for a syntax like `f{1, 2, 3}`, I see no technical problem, but then the `f` would have an entirely different meaning than it has in `f"..."`. A solution which wouldn't require new syntax could be for sets to have a read-only `.frozen` property which returns `frozenset(self)`, and the compiler could have a special case for expressions like `{1, 2, 3}.frozen` to compile them to `frozenset` constants.

Comment: For some reason I pictured that it would be `\`{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: `⛄️{1, 2, 3}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sentence above what you linked is the answer (emphasis mine):

> Non-empty sets (**not frozensets**) can be created by placing a
> comma-separated list of elements within braces, for example: `{'jack', 'sjoerd'}`, in addition to the `set` constructor.

So in short, no, there is no way to do that